# Is it possible to find a limit of a product of functions, provided limits of their sum and difference are known?

Tags: limits

I have an exercise in a textbook, which asks:

> If $\lim_{x \to a}[f(x) + g(x)] = 2$ and $\lim_{x \to a}[f(x) - g(x)] = 1$, find $\lim_{x \to a}[f(x)g(x)]$

My answer was, that this is impossible to find, while the correct answer from the textbook was $\frac{3}{4}$. I understand, how the provided answer was obtained, that is by finding separately $\lim_{x \to a}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x \to a}g(x)$, by solving the system of two equations.

But, from my understanding, one can use the limit laws for the sum/product etc. only if the limits, which comprise it, do exist (**and there was no mention of this in the exercise**). This is even explicitly stated in the same textbook, that is:

> Suppose that c is a constant and **the limits** $\lim_{x \to a}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x \to a}g(x)$ **exist**, then: …[*then the limit laws are listed*].

Here is just one example, when the law $\lim_{x \to a}[f(x) + g(x)] = \lim_{x \to a}f(x) + \lim_{x \to a}g(x)$ cannot be applied, if any of the limits $\lim_{x \to a}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x \to a}g(x)$ doesn't exist:

$
\lim_{x \to 4}(\frac{2x}{x - 4} - \frac{8}{x - 4}) \ne \lim_{x \to 4}\frac{2x}{x - 4} - \lim_{x \to 4}\frac{8}{x - 4}
$

Am I correct, and this can be considered an error in the textbook, or am I missing something? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}2f(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow a}[(f(x)+g(x))+(f(x)-g(x))]=\lim_{x\rightarrow a}[f(x)+g(x)]+\lim_{x\rightarrow a}[f(x)-g(x)]=3$ $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow a}2^{-1}2f(x)=2^{-1}\lim_{\rightarrow a}2f(x)=3/2$, similar to $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}g(x)$.

Because both $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}[f(x)+g(x)]$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}[f(x)-g(x)]$ exist, we can use the sum formula to get the existence of $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}2f(x)$, and because $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}2f(x)$ exists, we can use the scalar multiple rule to get the existence of $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}2^{-1}2f(x)$.